# How to properly quote a paper with two different years (original & actual)?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I need to quote a paper that was published in 1999 but started circulating around 1970 (I don't remember the exact year, but it's easy to find). I am now writing the following sentence, which is unfortunately false:

```
Since \citeauthor{maskin}'s \citeyearpar{maskin} seminal contribution, 
several necessary and sufficient conditions towards different types of 
implementation have been proposed and studied.

@article{maskin,
title = "Nash Equilibrium and Welfare Optimality",
author = "Eric Maskin",
journal = "Review of Economic Studies",
volume = "66",
number = "1",
pages = "23--38",
year = "1999",
url = "https://doi.org/10.1111%2F1467-937x.00076"
}
```

The sentence I'm writing reads as follows:

`Since Maskin's (1999) seminal contribution, several necessary and sufficient conditions towards different types of implementation have been proposed and studied.`

Unfortunately, the sentence is false because many of the contributions I'm mentioning are prior to 1999. Hence, my question:

*Is there a way to add the original year in which the paper started circulating in the biblatex reference? If there is a way to do so, how should I quote it in order to make sure that the resulting sentence is actually true?*

Comment: Depending on the style you are using, you could add the field `origdate`, but that would be, strictly speaking, wrong, since the paper was not *published* then. I'd suggest you put a remark in the field `annotation` or, even better, add an explanation in wriiting

Comment: I appreciate your comment. I will wait for other suggestions & if no other worthwhile suggestions show up, I'll follow your advice and ask it to write it as an answer for me to accept it.

Comment: I'm not sure this is really a TeX question. If the historical facts about the prior circulation of the paper are relevant, then you should simply explain them either in the text or in a footnote. But since the published version of the paper only appeared in 1999, that's really the only sensible way to cite it. So reword your sentence to make it true. ;) Maskin himself doesn't provide a reference to the 1977 version independently, but just mentions that this version has minimal changes.

Comment: Fair enough! I may have made a mistake by thinking it was a TeX question. I thought that maybe there was a natural way to deal with those cases in TeX.

Comment: Biblatex is flexible enough that several solutions are possible. `Publication` in the wider sense of "anything with a readership" (or, indeed,a listenership), can use `misc` or `unpublished` entry types (with notes). Circulation of unofficial literature, like samizdat or pre-doi "preprints" or anything in a non-typeset version(s), are conceptually like a pre-internet version of blog posts, so an equivalent of the `urlseen` field could be defined (`workcirc`?). For clustering versions, the `crossref` field with its data inheritance could be used. Or a custom `relatedstring` etc could be set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the `origyear` and `addendum` fields. The first two solutions are standard. The third one, on the other hand, is unusual, although in my opinion clear enough. You can also reverse `year` and `origyear` if you prefer (fourth solution).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{maskin,
  title = "Nash Equilibrium and Welfare Optimality",
  author = "Eric Maskin",
  journal = "Review of Economic Studies",
  volume = "66",
  number = "1",
  pages = "23--38",
  year = "1999",
  origyear = {1977},
  addendum = {Originally disclosed in 1977}, 
  url = "https://doi.org/10.1111%2F1467-937x.00076"
}
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareFieldFormat{origyear}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{origyearB}{\mkbibparens{#1\mkbibbrackets{\printfield{year}}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{origyearC}{\mkbibparens{\printfield{year}\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}

\begin{document}

Since \citeauthor{maskin}'s \citefield{maskin}[origyear]{origyear} seminal contribution, several necessary and sufficient conditions towards different types of implementation have been proposed and studied \parencite{maskin}.

Since \citeauthor{maskin}'s \citefield{maskin}[origyear]{origyear} seminal contribution \parencite{maskin}, several necessary and sufficient conditions towards different types of implementation have been proposed and studied.

Since \citeauthor{maskin}'s \citefield{maskin}[origyearB]{origyear} seminal contribution, several necessary and sufficient conditions towards different types of implementation have been proposed and studied.

Since \citeauthor{maskin}'s \citefield{maskin}[origyearC]{origyear} seminal contribution, several necessary and sufficient conditions towards different types of implementation have been proposed and studied.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

## Edit 1. Another, "logically" better, solution

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{maskin,
  title = "Nash Equilibrium and Welfare Optimality",
  author = "Eric Maskin",
  journal = "Review of Economic Studies",
  volume = "66",
  number = "1",
  pages = "23--38",
  year = "1999",
  origyear = {1977},
  addendum = {Originally disclosed in 1977}, 
  url = "https://doi.org/10.1111%2F1467-937x.00076"
}

@unpublished{maskin-unpub,
  title = "Nash Equilibrium and Welfare Optimality",
  author = "Eric Maskin",
  year = {1977},
  addendum = {Manuscript. See \textcite{maskin}}
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Since \citeauthor{maskin}'s \citeyearpar{maskin-unpub} seminal contribution, several necessary and sufficient conditions towards different types of implementation have been proposed and studied.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

## Edit 2. A last solution. Maybe the best one in my opinion

```
Since \citeauthor{maskin}'s seminal contribution in \citefield{maskin}
{origyear}, several necessary and sufficient conditions towards 
different types of implementation have been proposed and studied 
\parencite{maskin}.
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: The first two of these are simply wrong: you're citing a 1977 work that simply doesn't exist. Alternatively cite the 1977 paper as an unpublished manuscript independently.  This is usually only done if the two versions of the paper differ substantially (which in this case, they don't.) The second two are somewhat better, but really only the last one makes any sense given the actual bibliography. As I suggested in the comment, rewriting the sentence to reflect the historical details (if needed) and citing the 1999 paper as 1999 is really the only reasonable way to do this, IMO.

Comment: I added another possible solution. The 1977 "paper" in considered an @unpublished work (which in a sense is also a bibliography "object"). In the addendum field it refers to the "real" bibliography entry (1999).

Comment: I am most likely adopting your last suggestion. Thank you very much for putting the time to solve my issue --I do appreciate it.